# Отменить повторное событие click при вызове модального окна

Tags: jquery

При клике на ссылки с классом `.widget-settings` я вызываю модальное окно. Функцию `popupModalAjax` для вызова модального окна писал сам.

```
$('body').on('click', '.widget-settings a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    popupModalAjax({
        url: path + '/popup/',
        type: 'GET',
        callbacks: {
            ajaxContentAdd: function(){
                $('body').on('click', '.pop-heading', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('YRA');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Т.е. в функцию `popupModalAjax` я передаю массив данных, где `callbacks` => `ajaxContentAdd` является функцией.

```
function popupModalAjax(array){

    $.ajax({
        url: array['url'],
        type: array['type'],        
        success: function(res){                               
            popupModal(res);/*Функция для подгрузки модального окна*/

            var t = array['callbacks']['ajaxContentAdd'];
            t();              
        }           
    });
}
```

Вообщем проблема заключается в следующем:

При первом вызове модального окна и при клике в этом уже окне на - `$('body').on('click', '.pop-heading', function(event){...}`, `alert('YRA');` выводится один раз при каждом клике на `.pop-heading`, после того как закроешь модальное окно и снова его вызовешь (т.е. 2 раз), при клике на `.pop-heading`, `alert('YRA');` срабатывает уже два раза подряд, получается потому что вызвал второй раз модальное окно. И так вывод этих алертов при каждом клике по `.pop-heading` увеличивается до того кол-ва, сколько раз вызовешь модальное окно на странице без перезагрузки, после того как перезагрузишь страницу, счетчик обнуляется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уже знакомы с идеей *делегирования* обработки событий. Нет необходимости вызывать `$('body').on('click', '.pop-heading', ...` больше одного раза. Причем этот вызов может быть сделан *до* появления на странице элементов с классом `pop-heading`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.pop-heading', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('YRA');
});

$('body').on('click', '.widget-settings a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    popupModalAjax({
        url: path + '/popup/',
        type: 'GET',
        callbacks: {
            ajaxContentAdd: function(){
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

Хорошо. Раз уж Вы упорствуете:

```
$('body').on('click', '.widget-settings a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    popupModalAjax({
        url: path + '/popup/',
        type: 'GET',
        callbacks: {
            ajaxContentAdd: function(){
                $('.pop-heading').on('click', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('YRA');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Не вижу варианта решения моего вопроса. Я пишу универсальную функцию модального окна, чтобы можно было ее вызывать много раз и передавать в `ajaxContentAdd` различные функции и вызывать их, которые в свою очередь будут срабатывать в модальном окне.

Comment: @Дима Всмотритесь внимательнее в код. Попробуйте скопировать его к себе. Про Вашу "универсальность" мне ничего не известно.

Comment: Всмотрелся не раз внимательно:) Модальное окно подгружается в `DOM`, затем после закрытия удаляется из `DOM`. Еще раз напишу, мне нужно передавать в `ajaxContentAdd` различные функции, чтобы производить различные действия при кликах по ссылкам уже находящихся в модальном окне. У Вас же в `ajaxContentAdd: function(){}` пусто. Не очень понятен Ваш ответ на мой вопрос:(

Comment: Теперь понял. Спасибо большое Вам за помощь:)

Comment: @Дима Пожалуйста. Успехов!